# AutoHotKey Send Dynamic Key

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to create a script with a user-configurable hotkey

I can bind to the dynamic hotkey, but I can't seem to send a hotkey.

Here is a simple script illustrating the problem

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance, Force
btn1 := "F1"
btn5 := "F5"
Hotkey, %btn1% Up, stop1
Hotkey, %btn5% Up, stop5

stop1() {
  MsgBox f1 was released, sending f1 dynamically
  Send {%btn1%}
}

stop5() {
  MsgBox f5 was released, sending f1 statically
  Send {F1}
}
```

If I press F1, it triggers `start1`, and attempts to send F1 dynamically, as it's set in the header of the script. Nothing happens.

If I press F5, it triggers `start5`, and sends F1 statically. If your focused program uses that binding, the command is executed.

In my actual script, I need to be able to `Send {%btn1% up}` and `Send {%btn1% down}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version of your script works for me:

```
#Persistent
btn1 := "F1"
btn5 := "F5"
Hotkey, %btn1% up, stop1
Hotkey, %btn5% up, stop5
return

stop1:
  MsgBox f1 was released, sending f1 dynamically
  Send {%btn5%}
  return

stop5:
  MsgBox f5 was released, sending f1 statically
  Send {F1}
  return
```

You are mostly missing the `return` commands.

Comment: Adding `return` to my version didn't help, BUT changing to your function syntax does work. I'd like to understand why, but thanks for your help!

Comment: AutoHotKey has only a very basic syntax, so it's safer to stick to the syntax from the documentation.

Comment: @RegularJo I guess it is because variables are local in a function. Try adding `global btn1`  inside stop1().